# How do I put a specific order to Jbehave story execution?

Tags: jbehave

When you submit sorties to Jbehave with

```
@Override
public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() 
{
         return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), 
                 new LoginSteps(), new PreferencesSteps(), new BetterSteps());
}
```

They are executed in BetterSteps, LoginSteps, PreferencesStpes fasion.
How do I make these classes having scenarios execute in a custom order which is not alphabetical?
Say LoginSteps followed by PreferenceSteps followed by BetterSteps etc?

Answer (score 1):

There is a work around for your problem..

You can make your story name starting from Sn where n is 1,2,3..... like `S1_LoginSteps`, `S2_PreferenceSteps`

Jbehave will execute stories alphabetical starting from S1 then S2....

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you correctly that you have steps with identical or similar patterns in all of these steps classes and want to control which of them are used over others?

If so, have a look at step prioritization here: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/prioritising-steps.html and apply priorities to your preferred steps.

Comment: Nopes..I have these story files with names say login_steps.story, preference_steps.story, other_setps.story. Now when I provide their corresponding classes as mentioned above then they are run in alphabetical order. I want to run these in a specific order. How do I configure these. Say run LoginSteps() first then run PreferenceSteps() then something else...etc...

Comment: Ok, in that case it is a bit confusing for me as I'd think of steps-classes only to contain steps - not stories. You might want to rearrange your setup here. Apart from that, the order of story execution can (and should) not be fixed, but if your stories have explicit dependencies, try using "Given Stories" ( http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/given-stories.html )